# Each ball is contained in one of the green rooms "A, B, and C" or "A, B, or C"?

Tags: grammar

Are the two different versions of the sentence equivalent?

It seems to me that

> Each ball is contained in one of the green rooms A, B, and C.

forms the group of green rooms which comprises rooms A, B, and C, and states that each ball is contained in one of those rooms.

The second statement

> Each ball is contained in one of the green rooms A, B, or C.

focuses on the fact that each ball is contained in one of the green rooms, and specifies that such a green room can be A, B, or C.

Perhaps in the second version a comma should be introduced.

> Each ball is contained in one the green rooms, A, B, or C.

It seems to me there is only a slight difference in the two versions, but in any case the meaning is the same; A, B, and C are the only green rooms we have, and each ball is contained in one of them.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you consider that "A, B and/or C" refers to the *green rooms*, "and" may be ok. If it refers to *one of the rooms*, "or" is appropriate. I would say "Each ball is contained in one the green rooms, i.e. A, B, or C".

Comment: If it were my sentence to control, I would render it as "Each of the green rooms—A, B, and C—contains one of the balls." My reasoning is that the original wording doesn't make entirely clear whether there are three balls, one each in each of the three rooms (the meaning that my revision assumes), or whether there are an unspecified number of balls, all of them in one of the three rooms (in which case I would be inclined to render the sentence as "One of the green rooms—A, B, or C—contains all of the balls"). Of course, some people hate em dashes.

Comment: It it were my green room to control, I would prohibit ball-playing therein: it plays havoc with costume and makeup. (Ditto for balling, BTW.) ;)

Comment: Unless there are other rooms  or things that could be mistaken for green rooms (D, E, F... etc), there's no reason to say "A, B, *and* C". The appositive construction would be used when identifying which of the rooms or other labeled items on a drawing are "the green rooms", because the appositive shifts emphasis from the ball distribution to the room layout.

Comment: Both are grammatical.  The question is one of logic, and perhaps of style, not of grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Each ball is contained in one of the green rooms A, B, and C.
>
> Each ball is contained in one of the green rooms A, B, or C.

In the "and" variant, the group referenced by "A, B, and C" is apposite "green rooms".  In the "or" variant, each item in the list "A, B, or C" is apposite "one".

One would use the "and" variant when there are other labeled rooms, or things that might be taken for rooms, (D, E, F...) which  could be mistaken for green rooms. The apposition with "green rooms" would identify which rooms are the green rooms and which are not.   The apposition with "one" would identify the distribution of balls among an unambiguous array of green rooms.

Answer (score 0):

On reading the above it seems (to me at least) that neither of the above is unambiguous. This mainly has to do with the start of the phrase `Each ball`. For example, is this one ball or multiple balls (each of the four balls are in room A,B, or C)?

I would think the above would be clearer with something like:

```
There are three green rooms: A, B, and C.
There is one ball.
One and only one of the green rooms contains the ball.
```

And then if required, condense the logic down into a single sentence:

```
There are three green rooms--A, B, and C--one of which contains a ball.
```

Comment: Let's simplify by saying that "We have 10 balls. Each of the balls is contained in one of the green rooms..."

I think the first version could be reformatted to:

Each ball is contained in one of the green rooms: A, B, and C.